# issues with loopback4 jwt authentication

Tags: javascript, typescript, jwt, loopbackjs, loopback4

I'm having issues authenticating jwt token whenever I use /login or /signup api endpoint.
Here is my users controller:

```
import {authenticate, TokenService} from '@loopback/authentication';
import {
  Credentials, MyUserService,
  TokenServiceBindings,
  User,
  UserRepository,
  UserServiceBindings
} from '@loopback/authentication-jwt';
import {inject} from '@loopback/core';
import {
  repository
} from '@loopback/repository';
import {
  get, getModelSchemaRef, post,

  requestBody
} from '@loopback/rest';
import {SecurityBindings, securityId, UserProfile} from '@loopback/security';
import {genSalt, hash} from 'bcryptjs';
import _ from 'lodash';
import {Users} from '../models';

const CredentialsRequestBody = {
  description: 'Input of login function',
  required: true,
  content: {
    'application/json': {schema: Users}
  }
}

export class UserController {
  constructor(
    @inject(TokenServiceBindings.TOKEN_SERVICE) public jwtService: TokenService,
    @inject(UserServiceBindings.USER_SERVICE) public userService: MyUserService,
    @inject(SecurityBindings.USER, {optional: true}) public user: UserProfile,
    @repository(UserServiceBindings.USER_REPOSITORY) protected userRepository: UserRepository,
  ) { }
  @post('/login', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Token',
        content: {
          'application/json': {
            schema: {
              type: 'object',
              properties: {
                token: {
                  type: 'string'
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
  async login(
    @requestBody(CredentialsRequestBody) creditionals: Credentials
  ): Promise<{token: string}> {
    console.log('hekkkkk')
    const user = await this.userService.verifyCredentials(creditionals);
    console.log('kayyy', user)
    const userProfile = this.userService.convertToUserProfile(user);
    console.log('break')
    const token = await this.jwtService.generateToken(userProfile);
    console.log('break 1')
    return {token};
  }

  @authenticate('jwt')
  @get('/whoami', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: '',
        schema: {
          type: 'string'
        }
      }
    }
  })

  async whoAmI(
    @inject(SecurityBindings.USER) currentUserProfile: UserProfile
  ): Promise<string> {
    console.log('here')
    return currentUserProfile[securityId];
  }

  @post('/signup', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'User',
        content: {
          'application/json': {
            schema: {
              'x-ts-type': User
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })

  async signUp(
    @requestBody({
      content: {
        'application/json': {
          schema: getModelSchemaRef(Users, {
            title: 'NewUser'
          })
        }
      }
    })
    newUserRequest: Users
  ): Promise<User> {
    const password = await hash(newUserRequest.password, await genSalt());
    const savedUser = await this.userRepository.create(
      _.omit(newUserRequest, 'password')
    );
    console.log('break 1')
    await this.userRepository.userCredentials(savedUser.id).create({password});
    console.log('break 2')

    return savedUser;
  }
}
```

Here is my sequence.ts file:

```
import {
  AuthenticateFn,
  AuthenticationBindings,
  AUTHENTICATION_STRATEGY_NOT_FOUND,
  USER_PROFILE_NOT_FOUND
} from '@loopback/authentication';
import {
  Context
} from '@loopback/context';
import {inject} from '@loopback/core';
// import {MiddlewareSequence} from '@loopback/rest';
import {
  FindRoute,
  InvokeMethod,
  ParseParams,
  Reject, RequestContext,
  RestBindings,
  Send,
  SequenceActions,
  SequenceHandler
} from '@loopback/rest';

// export class MySequence extends MiddlewareSequence { }
export class MySequence implements SequenceHandler {
  constructor(
    @inject(RestBindings.Http.CONTEXT) public ctx: Context,
    @inject(SequenceActions.FIND_ROUTE) protected findRoute: FindRoute,
    @inject(SequenceActions.PARSE_PARAMS) protected parseParams: ParseParams,
    @inject(SequenceActions.INVOKE_METHOD) protected invoke: InvokeMethod,
    @inject(SequenceActions.SEND) public send: Send,
    @inject(SequenceActions.REJECT) public reject: Reject,
    @inject(AuthenticationBindings.AUTH_ACTION)
    protected authenticateRequest: AuthenticateFn
  ) { }
  async handle(context: RequestContext) {
    try {
      const {request, response} = context;
      const route = this.findRoute(request);
      console.log('jau', route)
      await this.authenticateRequest(request);
      const args = await this.parseParams(request, route);
      console.log('kel', args, response, await this.invoke(route, args))
      const result = await this.invoke(route, args);
      console.log('pop', result, response)
      this.send(response, result);
      console.log('done1')
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log('may', err.code)
      if (
        err.code === AUTHENTICATION_STRATEGY_NOT_FOUND ||
        err.code === USER_PROFILE_NOT_FOUND
      ) {
        Object.assign(err, {statusCode: 401});
      }
      this.reject(context, err)
      console.log('done2')
    }
  }
}
```

Incase if you're wondering about the db. I've connected to **mongodb** and have no connection issues.

I get statusCode 500 and issues like:

```
Request POST /login failed with status code 500. ResolutionError: The key 'repositories.repositories.UserRepository' is not bound to any value in context RequestContext-nP8Bsm4XRqSs9_f7D1VuEQ-3 (context: RequestContext-nP8Bsm4XRqSs9_f7D1VuEQ-3, binding: repositories.repositories.UserRepository, resolutionPath: controllers.UserController --> @UserController.constructor[3])
```

If you need access to the entire codebase please look at:
https://github.com/compressionmonkey/dummyloopbackserver

I've been googling the issue for a week now(I watched multiple tutorials including the ones from IBM and have crosschecked against IBM github codebases) so finally I am asking this question on stackoverflow.

Constructive feedback is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like your question was answered in https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/6964. Please feel free to ping there or open a new issue if you have further questions. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my question again after facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

The following change can help to solve the issue:

Change this line in `user.controller.ts`:

```
@repository(UserServiceBindings.USER_REPOSITORY) protected userRepository: UserRepository,
```

**to**

```
@repository(UserRepository) protected userRepository: UserRepository,
```

**Cause of the issue:**
The `UserServiceBindings.USER_REPOSITORY` is translating to `repositories.repositories.UserRepository` on the runtime and then the app is trying to find the repository with it. Since the repository is actually present in the app context with the key `repositories.UserRepository` it couldn't find the repository and hence throws the exception.

The following debugging screen image can help understand it better, please check:

[Check VSCode debug screenshot by clicking here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNYrn.png)

In the image, I have modified the code a little to showcase the issue in realtime:

- Point **1** shows the expected line of code.
- Point **2** uses the `isBound` method to check whether the key is bound to something in the app context or not.
- Point **3** shows the booelan outcome of the `isBound` method for both of the binding keys.

I hope the answer was helpful.